# One liner if else for /bin/sh

Tags: shell, sh

I do realise that I've written code for bash. However it's using /bin/sh in this case. How do I re-write this.

This:

```
Step 8/17 : RUN if [ "$KEY" == "" ] ; then echo "SSH key is not set, aborting" ; exit 1 ; else echo "SSH key is set" ; fi
```

Results in:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [: unexpected operator
```

And this:

```
Step 7/15 : RUN if test "$KEY" == "" ; then echo "SSH key is not set, aborting" ; exit 1 ; else echo "SSH key is set" ; fi
```

Results in:

```
/bin/sh: 1: test: unexpected operator
```

Comment: It's not the one-liner that's the problem, it's the `==`. The only POSIX-defined string comparison operator is `=`; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html.

Comment: ...you could have reduced it to just `test "$KEY" == ""` and gotten the same problem, thus factoring out the `if` for a tighter [mcve].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy By all means do so, but first point to where because I couldn't find any that had examples for one liners.

Comment: ...but you can reproduce the problem *without* having it be a one-liner. The "one-liner" aspect of this was a red herring, and further testing would have allowed you to discard it as an essential element of the issue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So multiple line can be written as one liners, is it just to remove the line break? (I don't sit with shell scripting often as you can probably tell)

Comment: Just remove the line breaks and replace them with `;`s in places where they were syntactically necessary (and where no `;` or `&` existed before -- you can't double up command separators), and yes, you can transform any multi-line code in bash to a one-liner.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you! I did not know this and I'm probably not the only one who didn't. I'll go read the other questions now :)